# Graduations in kung-fu for kids?

Tags: training, kung-fu

I'm looking for graduations in kung-fu for kids. Something similar to the program of ABRSM in music or the judo-kan.

I think there must exist a curriculum already in different schools and different Styles.

Comment: https://www.ymaaboston.com/kids-ranking-system.html

Comment: Is this to help in designing your own syllabus? Is it for practical/traditional/sport purposes?
This may make it easier to narrow down pertinent examples.

Answer (score 0):

There exist many such graduations.

The majority of martial arts styles have their own system of graduation and Chinese styles are no exception.  However these rarely align with each other.

Also note that while Japanese style at least agree on names for grades (some number to  1st kyu and then 1st to 9th dan) I have never seen a standardised Chinese grading system.

I practice a Japanese kung-fu style which uses the Japanese grading sequence but that's very rare of course.

Generally you will get various coloured sashes... and that's about all you can be sure of.

Answer (score 0):

The EWTO (European Wing Tsun Organisation, under GM Keith Kernspecht) has a strong focus on children and teens in their "Kids-WT" programs together with graduations. Some places have more classes for kids than for adults. They are mostly active in Germany, Austria and Switzerland.